# Serilog custom library need to capture RemoteIP and remoteUSer in distributed environment

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, serilog

I have created one common custom library using serilog package, the idea here is all the applications should use this custom library instead of using serilog directly so that there is change in one place, I want to capture remote IP, remote user[authenticated] and co-relationID, how to code that in custom library, below is my code.

```
  public class SerilogLogger: ISerilogLogger
    {        
        public static void CreateInstance(IConfiguration config)
        {
            Log.Logger=new LoggerConfiguration()
           .ReadFrom.Configuration(config)
           .Enrich.WithEnvironmentUserName()
           .Enrich.WithMachineName()           
           .CreateLogger();
        }
}
```

Applications sending custom configuration from appsettings.json file

```
 "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Default": "Information",
        "Microsoft": "Error",
        "System": "Error"
      }
    },
    "WriteTo": [

      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "C:\\Users\\Documents\\Important\\log.json",
          //"outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ffff}|{TenantName}|{RequestId}|{SourceContext}|{Level:u3}|{Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}",
          "rollOnFileSizeLimit": true,
          "retainedFileCountLimit": 20,
          "rollingInterval": "Day",
          "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Information",
          "fileSizeLimitBytes": 1,
          // "textformatter": "SerilogManager.Formatter.ElasticsearchJsonFormatter",
          "formatter": "Serilog.Formatting.Json.JsonFormatter, Serilog"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: An IP connection (TCP) contains no authentication info.  You can use roles in a HTTP connection.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-security/roles/creating-and-managing-roles-cs

Comment: @jdweng I'm looking for a solution in library which is using serilog, I can achieve the same directly using serilog package.